# SQL, How do i display all info after entering a start date

Tags: java

this is my user interface where i would prompt them to enter a starting date

```
public void viewAllTicket() throws Exception {

        String ticketDate;
        int dd = 0, mm = 0, yy = 0;
        boolean dateDNE = true;
        String result[] = null;
        int transactionId = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter start date: ");
        ticketDate=scan.nextLine();
        
        result = db.retrieveAllRecords();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%-10s %10s %10s %20s %10s\n", "Ticket Date |", "Transaction Id |", "Number of Tickets |",
                "Member Phone Number |", "Total Price");
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 80; cnt++)
            System.out.print("=");
        System.out.println();
        for (String temp : result)
            System.out.println(temp);
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

this is in my DBController where it displays all the records

```
public String[] retrieveAllRecords() throws Exception {
        String arr[] = null;
        int count = 0;

        String sql5 = "SELECT * FROM `themepark`";

        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sql5);

        if (result.last()) {
            count = result.getRow();
            arr = new String[count];
            result.beforeFirst();
        }
        count = 0;
        while (result.next()) {
            String tempDate = result.getString("Ticket_Date");
            int tempId = result.getInt("Transaction_Id");
            int tempTicket = result.getInt("Number_of_Tickets");
            int tempPhoneNumber = result.getInt("Member_Phone_Number");
            int tempTotalPrice = result.getInt("Total_Price");

            String temp = String.format("%-10s %10d %18d %22d %15d", tempDate, tempId, tempTicket, tempPhoneNumber,
                    tempTotalPrice);
            arr[count] = temp;
            count++;
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DBController db = new DBController();
        String ticketDate = null;
        String temp[] = db.retrieveAllRecords();
        for (String t : temp)
            System.out.println(t);

    }
}
```

so currently with these 2 classes, i would be displaying all the ticket transaction info.

My question is, if i were to prompt user to enter a start date of a ticket, how/what do i do to only display ticket transaction info from the start date onwards

For example, if these are all the ticket dates of the transactions, `14th feb,14th feb,14th feb,15th feb,15th feb,16th feb,17th feb`

fter prompting user for start date,
`Enter start date: 15th feb`

Output would be:
`15th feb,15th feb,16th feb,17th feb`

I appreciate any help given

Answer (score 0):

You would parse the user’s input as a `LocalDate` object.

You would define the date column in your database table to be of a data type akin to the SQL-standard type `DATE`.

You would add a `WHERE` clause to your SQL to search for date values after the user-specified date.

You would rewrite your SQL statement to be a prepared statement. Then pass the `LocalDate` in a call to `setObject`.

When retrieving data you would use `getObject` on your `ResultSet` to obtain a `LocalDate` object.

All of these topics have been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.